# Using awk, "if", then sed

Tags: unix, if-statement, awk, sed

```
awk '{ if (NR -ge $num && NR -le $num_max && $1 == $UM); 
then sed 's/'$UM'/'$UM_lower'/g'dipping_CR_UM_change.txt > new.txt}'
```

I get the following error

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
    { if (NR -ge $num && NR -le $num_max && $1 == $UM); then sed >>>  s/$UM/$UM_lower/gdipping_CR_UM_change. <<< txt > new.txt}

awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

Comment: The book mentioned by Ed Morton is free:
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/

Comment: @RicardoBranco selling that book is the only money the guy who provides GNU awk gets for the massive amount of time he puts into GNU awk and the documentation, I think we should all recommend people buy the book rather than referring them to the online version which he has graciously made available for us to use for reference.

Comment: @EdMorton The link I provided mentions that and has the option for buying it.  I didn't provide the link to the PDF.

Comment: @RicardoBranco It's sold through O'Reilly, not the FSF: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033820.do

Comment: I'm currently using my advisor's "sed & awk" guide by Dale Dougherty & Arnold Robbins (O'Reilly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The power of Awk lets you pass variables and make the sed part with the gsub() function:

```
awk -v UM="$UM" -v UM_lower="$UM_lower" -v num="$num" '{ if (NR > num && NR < num_max && $1 == UM) { gsub(UM, UM_lower) } print $0 }'
```

Comment: Thanks! If I've defined UM, UM_lower, etc. before the awk line, do they need to be defined again with the -v?

Comment: Yes.  The -v option is used to pass to Awk variables.  In this case, we use environment variables.

Comment: how does awk know what .txt file to access? it isn't defined in your statement?

Comment: Pipe the output of the txt file through awk like this: `cat input.txt | awk ...`

Comment: I got it working. I truly appreciate your help and swift responses. Thank you, again!

Comment: I pressed the green tick. When I pressed the up arrow this message appeared: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.